# Do browser caches support HTTP cache channels?

Tags: http, caching, cross-browser, browser-cache

I am looking to implement a Restful event mechanism or server push using HTTP cache channels however its not clear to me whether browser caches actually support cache-channels at all, and if they do, which ones?

Comment: What is a "cache channel" in HTTP?

Comment: HTTP Cache Channels are described in the following places among others:  1) http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1352-how-to-keep-caches-fresh-and-warm/  2) https://www.mnot.net/blog/2008/01/04/cache_channels 3) Book: "REST in Practice" 4) HTTP Cache Channels are supported by Squid Proxy Server